# R Shiny - Insert a Second Reactive Slider in Shiny using leafletProxy() - Edited and with data

Tags: r, slider, shiny, leaflet, rstudio

I am a beginner in R mapping and I am trying to build an R Shiny app to visualise Student Satisfaction and Ranking for all the universities in the UK.

Through leaflet I have mapped the university locations with markers and added sliders with popups to see the student Satisfaction Score and the Ranking (see screenshot).

The idea is to be able to choose a set of values on the sliders (say "Satisfaction from 80 to 90" and "Ranking from 1 to 30" and the app would only display the ones that fit both criteria.

The problem lies within having multiple reactive sliders. If I code the Ranking slider the same way as the Satisfaction slider, the Satisfaction slider takes on the Ranking values instead of the two sliders working together.

Below you can see my code so far with a screenshot of how it looks as well as the data (parts of the Ranking slider are commented so they don't interfere).

Any tips how to continue so the two slider don't take values from each other?

Thanks a lot and sorry if the question is very basic.

```
        library(dplyr)
        library(shiny)
        library(leaflet)


        mapData <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Shiny app/Csv Shiny Data Clean.csv") %>%
          filter(!is.na(Latitude) & !is.na(Longitude))


     ui <- bootstrapPage(
          tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, 
                     body {width:100%;height:100%}"),

          leafletOutput("uniSmap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),


     #slider for student satisfaction

      absolutePanel(
            top = 50,
            right = 50,
            sliderInput(
              "range",
              "Satisfaction Score",
              min = 1,
              max = 100,
              value = round(range(mapData$Satisfaction.....2016.Registered,   na.rm = TRUE), 1),
              step = 1
            )
          ),


     #slider for Ranking

      absolutePanel(
            top = 200,
            right = 50,
            sliderInput(
              "range",
              "QS University Ranking",
              min = 1,
              max = 128,
              value = round(range(mapData$QS.Ranking, na.rm = TRUE), 1),
              step = 1
            )
          ),

          #bottom right title
          absolutePanel(
            bottom = 10,
            left = 10,
            "Satisfaction Map 2016"
          )
          )


    server <- function(input, output, session) {

          filteredData <- reactive({
            mapData %>%
              filter(Satisfaction.....2016.Registered >= input$range[1] &
                       Satisfaction.....2016.Registered <= input$range[2]) 
          })


            #question here: can I just do the same for Ranking Data (as below)?

            # filteredDataRanking <- reactive({
            #   mapData %>%
            #     filter(QS.Ranking >= input$range[1] &
            #              QS.Ranking <= input$range[2]) 
            # })


      output$uniSmap <- renderLeaflet({
            # as the map is only drawn once
            # use non-reactive dataframe, mapData 
            leaflet(mapData) %>%
              addTiles() %>%
              fitBounds(~min(Longitude), ~min(Latitude), 
                        ~max(Longitude), ~max(Latitude))
          })

          # Incremental changes to the map performed in an observer.

          observe({

            leafletProxy("uniSmap", data = filteredData()) %>%

              clearShapes() %>% 
              clearPopups() %>% 
              clearMarkers() %>%

              addMarkers(lat = ~Latitude,
                         lng = ~Longitude,
                         popup = ~paste(
                           Institution,
                           "<br>",
                           "Overall Satisfaction:",
                           Satisfaction.....2016.Registered,
                           "<br>"
                         )
              )

            }) #end of observe for satisfaction


          #would I have to create another observe for ranking data (as below)?

          # observe({
          #   
          #   leafletProxy("uniSmap", data = filteredDataRanking()) %>%
          #     
          #     clearShapes() %>% 
          #     clearPopups() %>% 
          #     clearMarkers() %>%
          #     
          #     addMarkers(lat = ~Latitude,
          #                lng = ~Longitude,
          #                popup = ~paste(
          #                  Institution,
          #                  "<br>",
          #                  "QS University Ranking",
          #                  QS.Ranking,
          #                  "<br>"
          #                )
          #     )
          #   
          # }) #end of observe for Ranking






        } #end of server description

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)






#License: a substantial portion of code is Copyright by (c) 2017 Stephen McDaniel
```

[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJR4x.jpg)

link to the data: [csv_shiny](http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/mLu1ebH)

Comment: Welcome! See how to improve your post to help others help you, here: [mcve]

Comment: Look into leafletProxy() here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html.

Comment: should you be using `clearMarkers()` instead of `clearShapes()`?

Comment: If you want assistance you should provide data that others can use to reproduce your code. Use `dput(head(my_shiny_Data))` to add data to your question

Comment: You are calling data from your original data frame `my_shiny_data`, not your subset `reactiveData()`. You can fix this by deleting the variable name in your `leafletProxy` references. e.g. `lng = Longitude`, etc.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answers, that helped. as you can see I got some help and was able to work with leafletProxy(), which now works, but the question changed slightly.